# aligning and logo shape in moderncv

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, logos

How can I align the logos and the elements on their right side?

Another, and more important, problem that I face has to do their shape. As soon as I close TeXworks and try to open the pdf document I see the result of the right side of the following image. How can I fix it, so as to have it aligned and closer to the left side?
[image]

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pst-tree,array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating, hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\title{\bfseries\Huge Ioannis (Yannis) Galanakis}


\date{\footnotesize Updated on \today}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=color2,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.5\textwidth}

Athens, Greece
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.5\textwidth}
\faPhone{}    +30 210 \\
\faMobilePhone{}    +30 697 \\
\skypesocialsymbol giannis.galanak \\
 \faFacebookSign{} \href{}{Giannis}\\
\faLinkedinSign {} \href{}{Yannis}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi. You are not using the `moderncv` class in your MWE, please consider editing the title of your question as right now it may be misleading.

Comment: Do you run your codes with pdflatex? It does not work for me...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

To fix the alignment you can use a tabular environment to display the icons in one column, and the contact information in another.

The changed code might look like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pst-tree,array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating, hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\title{\bfseries\Huge Ioannis (Yannis) Galanakis}


\date{\footnotesize Updated on \today}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=color2,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.5\textwidth}

Athens, Greece

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
    \faPhone{}         & +30 210          \\
    \faMobilePhone{}   & +30 697          \\
    \skypesocialsymbol & giannis.galanak  \\
    \faFacebookSign{}  & \href{}{Giannis} \\
    \faLinkedinSign {} & \href{}{Yannis}  \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

If you prefer, you can change the alignment of the column with the icons, e.g.:

```
...
\begin{tabular}{cr} %(center-aligned left column, right-aligned right column)
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think the poster was asking for right alignment rather than left.  Also posting a complete document would be a useful supplement to the code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't see any reference to right alignment in the question, but perhaps the poster can clarify? In any case I've edited my answer to include all of the poster's original example.

Comment: The first sentence is: "How can I align the logos... on their right side?"

Comment: Sorry I misread it as referring to the block on the right - code edited.